# Using Github actions cache to avoid installing composer vendor

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I have a project which is using GitHub actions to build and deploy code. This project is a Wordpress theme based on sage (it does'n matter, but FIY). This project is using node_modules and composer vendors.

My deployment workflow is composed of 3 jobs :

- installing `node_modules` and build resources (js, css, etc.). I'm using cache to install `node_modules`, and it create a `/public` folder which is an artifact
- installing composer vendor. I'm using cache on vendors, it's faster.
- deploying through rsync

I'm getting `/public` folder on the 3rd step because it's an artifact, but I'm struggling deploying `/vendor` folder, because it doesn't exist on the 3rd job. I could use artifacts to send `/vendor` from 2nd to 3rd job, but it's a bit slow.

Do you know if there is a way to use cache to get /vendor folder on the 3rd step ? Do I need to re-run `composer install` on the last step in order to get this `/vendor` folder ? If so, my 2nd step is a bit useless isn't it ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caches *can* be used across multiple jobs as long as they're in the same workflow - you won't need to run `composer install` in both steps. Artifacts are only needed if you need to use the folder/files *outside* of your workflow.

As long as the first job will always run, you can use the same cache key for both steps and make the assumption that the cache will always exist during the third job.

Something like this would work for you. In a "normal" run (the workflow hasn't already been run for this `github.sha`), the first cache step will miss and `composer install` will run. Once `job-two` is finished, everything in `/vendor` will be cached with `github.sha` as the cache key. `job-three` will pick that `/vendor` folder up from the cache so you can use it in the rest of the steps.

```yaml
jobs:
  job-two:
    steps:
    - name: Cache vendor folder
      uses: actions/cache@v3
      with:
        path: /vendor
        key: ${{ github.sha }}

    - name: Build vendor folder
      run: composer install

  job-three:
    steps:
    - name: Retrieve cached vendor folder
      uses: actions/cache@v3
      with:
        path: /vendor
        key: ${{ github.sha }}
```

Hard to get it perfect without seeing your workflow file - you might have to tweak some of the paths.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you ! My mistake was to use the cache for composer items (avoiding downloading them each time) but not for the vendor folder. It's fully working now, thank you !